# i have a problem trying to connect to odbc

Tags: sql-server, linux, dockerfile, django-database, unixodbc

this is my dockerfile, or a fragment of where I'm trying to make the connection

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz -O openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.1.1l && ./config && make&& \
    make install && ldconfig
RUN apt-get update
# MS ODBC
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && apt-get -y install gcc gnupg2
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && apt-get update

RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

RUN apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
WORKDIR /.bashrc
```

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: I can't see anything that makes a connection

Comment: `.bashrc` is a file, why are you setting it as your `WORKDIR`? Is that the line throwing the error? It feels off.

Comment: You've got a whole lot of breakage there. Why `libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1` instead of the current `17.10.1.1-1` at `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.1.1`? Why are you installing `libgssapi-krb5-2` without also configuring the rest of Kerberos client support? Why are you manually installing `openssl-1.1.1l` instead of the current `1.1.1n-0+deb11u3` from the Debian 11 repos?

Comment: You are right, that was the error, I was able to fix it by changing the 2.1 to 1.1. thks